# Regular expression for initials of name with dashes on it

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been struggling with a regular expression to get the initials of a name with dashes.

For example,
John Smith, I should get JS

The regular expressions I have is the following:

```
name.match(/(^\S\S?|\b\S)?/g).join("").match(/(^\S|\S$)?/g).join("").toUpperCase()
```

However, it does not pick the correct inital for the last name. For example:

**John Andrew-Smith, I should get JA**

However, I get JS.

Why does it pick up the letter after dash, I am a bit confused.

Any help is much appreciated

EDIT: Sorry forgot to add this part, I should ignore any middle name initials. For example, John Andrew Smith, should be JS, not JAS. As Andrew would be considered a middle name

If the last name has dash, then it is part of the lastname, so Andrew-Smith, would be the last name

Comment: if there is a space between firstname and last name . why are you using regex ?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/MhH6r6/1 `name.match(/(^\S\S?|\b\S)?/g)` is incorrectly matching `Jo`, `A`, and `-S`. Then `.match(/(^\S|\S$)?/g)` is condensing this to `J` and `S`.

Comment: Is this some sort of regex challenge for yourself? Like ashish mentioned, you could do it with `name.split(" ").map((part) => part[0]).join("")`. Even works if they have a middle name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first split on spaces to get all initials in an array. Then join first and last elements from this array. So something like:

```
const allInitials = name.split(" ").map(n => n[0])
const initials = allInitials[0] + allInitials.splice(-1)
```

If you really want to use a regex, and do the above in one line you could do:

```
name.split(" ").map(n => n[0]).join("").replace(/^(.).*(.)$/g, "$1$2")
```

Silly me! The whole thing can just be:

```
name.replace(/^(.).*\s(.).*$/, "$1$2")
```

Basically, capture 1st initial, then greedy ignore all characters up to last whitespace character, then capture the next character, and then ignore all characters up to end of string

Comment: I'd also add that I'd highly recommend https://regex101.com/ for testing out regex expressions, and always bear in mind that there are sometimes easier ways to solve string manipulation than using such expressions.

Comment: You are using `map` which in my seem isn't an optimal way because it needs more time to run than a simple regex without it.

Comment: I've left previous examples just to see how we get to final solution. First solution (with map, and no regex) is better than second solution, as both map and regex are pretty slow beasts. I'd say map is quicker than regex, but I'd try it out on https://jsbench.me/ if it's important

Answer (score 0):

I would use `/(?<!-)[A-Z]/g`

```js
const names = [
  'John Smith',
  'John Andrew-Smith'
]

for (const name of names) {
  const initials = name.match(/(?<!-)[A-Z]/g).join('')
  console.log(name, initials)
}
```

Comment: Hey this looks good, but the issue is I want to ignore any middle names.

So if I have John Andrew Smith, I want the intial to be JS.

Just want the first and last name initials

Comment: @IbtasumIktadar you said - *John Andrew-Smith, I should get JA*

Comment: yes, but the dash makes it so it is part of the last name. So Andrew-Smith would be the last name. Whereas if there is no dash, it would be a middle name, so Andrew Smith, would be Andrew as middle name and Smith as last name

Comment: You should have added this information to the question

Answer (score 0):

A more straightforward approach using regex would be:

- match the first uppercase letter in a capture group `([A-Z])`
- then any other word characters `\w+`
- then a space `\s`
- then another uppercase letter in a capture group `([A-Z])`
- and then any other word characters `\w+`

`^([A-Z])\w+\s([A-Z])\w+`

Though as mentioned in the comments, regex is overkill for something like this.

```js
var getInitials = function(name) {
  return name.match(/^([A-Z])\w+\s([A-Z])\w+/).splice(1, 2).join("");
}

console.log(getInitials("John Smith"));
console.log(getInitials("John Andrew-Smith"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
const text = 'John Andrew Smith'
let result = /^(\S)\S+/g.exec(text)[1] + /(\S)\S+$/g.exec(text)[1];
document.write(result);
```

Because you said you don't want to match the middle name I decided to first match the first letter of the first word then concat it with the first letter of the last word.

`/^(\S)\S+/g` : Matches the first letter of a word from the beginning.

`/(\S)\S+$/g` : Matches the first letter of a word from the ending.